# Spring Data query with Specification and Pagination breaks during count operation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have the following repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository
    extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {

  Page<MyEntity> findAll(
      Specification<MyEntity> specification, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This query works fine without pagination (I already tried removing the pageable and returning a List and it works fine), but with pagination it breaks during the count with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [SqmListJoin(com.test.MyEntity(250011453794600).children(250011454204100))]
```

MyEntity has a undirectional relation @OneToMany with children.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Id private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")
  private List<Child> children;

  // ...
}
```

I instruct the Specification to fetch the children with:

```
root.fetch(MyEntity_.children, JoinType.INNER);
```

As I said, the query works fine without pagination, getting the correct results in one query (avoiding N+1 problem), but with pagination the count is not working.

How can I fix the count?

**UPDATE**

I verified that this problem happens to any JOIN operation. It seems that the count forces an JOIN FETCH for some reason.